# How can I smog check my car on Vancouver Island to renew my California Vehicle Registration?

Tags: canada, us-citizens, car, vehicle-registration

I just moved to Vancouver Island, Canada from California a little over a month ago. I just received the letter for the registration renewal which also says I need a STAR certified smog check for it. I searched for smog check places here on the island but found nothing. What options do I have? Do I need to bring my car back to the States in order to do this? 
Thank you for any or all responses.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this California government web site](https://www.bar.ca.gov/Consumer/Smog_Check_Program_General_Information.aspx#44-my-renewal-notice-says-my-vehicle-needs-a-smog-check-but-the-vehicle-is-located-out-of-state-and-will-not-be-back-for-many-months-its-too-far-to-bring-back-to-california-for-a-smog-inspection-can-i-get-my-vehicle-tested-in-another-state-and-send-the-results-to-dmv),

> **4.4 My renewal notice says my vehicle needs a Smog Check but the vehicle is located out of state and will not be back for many months.
>   It's too far to bring back to California for a smog inspection. Can I
>   get my vehicle tested in another state and send the results to DMV?**
>
> No. There is no need to get a smog inspection in another state, as it
>   will not be valid in California. In order to complete your
>   registration, simply fill out and sign DMV's Statement of Facts form
>   stating the reason why the vehicle cannot be tested. DMV will mail the
>   registration and license plate sticker to wherever the car is
>   currently located.

The Statement of Facts form is located [here](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/wcm/connect/35dae237-eb4b-4bed-a82a-b4c652c2ef8a/reg256.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CONVERT_TO=url&CACHEID=ROOTWORKSPACE-35dae237-eb4b-4bed-a82a-b4c652c2ef8a-mAQYGgO) (PDF).